# If it is captured in a block, does it ensure that the basic Ether transfer transaction is executed?

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas

I would like to verify that the Ether transfer was done reliably based on the transaction and block information in Solidity.

I know that in the execution of a contract such as ERC20, if the contract execution reverts in the middle, it will be captured in the block but the state will not change.
(I also know that it is possible to verify whether the state changes or not by checking the Transaction Receipt.)

In the case of a simple Ether transfer, for example, if there is not enough gas, it is not captured in the block.
so if it is captured in the block, can I assume that it is executed?
(Even if I look at the Transaction Receipt, I can't check the contents contained in the Receipt Root.)

Or do I need to check the state change itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A ether transfer between EOA (external owned accounts, e.g. non contracts) uses 21000 gas.

If you set the gas limit below the transaction will never be mined, it will not enter the pending transactions pool.

If the transfer doesn't have enough funds to cover value transferred and the transaction fees the transaction will not be mined, but it will remain in the pending pool until there's enough balance in the sender or it is dropped.

Comment: Thanks! 
I've understood that in the case of simple ether transfers, Invalid transactions for some reason are not mined or pooled in pending transactions :)